no matches for kind "K8sHorizontalPodAutoscaler" in version "constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1" ensure CRDs are installed first
I have been working around the GKE policy controller lately, and while applying the HPA policy as per this. I am getting the error
error: resource mapping not found for name: "horizontal-pod-autoscaler" namespace: "" from "hpa-policy.yaml": no matches for kind "HorizontalPodAutoscalerConstraint" in version "constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1"

ensure CRDs are installed first
HPA policy
apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: K8sHorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: horizontal-pod-autoscaler
spec:
  enforcementAction: deny
  match:
    kinds:
    - apiGroups:
      - autoscaling
      kinds:
      - HorizontalPodAutoscaler
  parameters:
    enforceScaleTargetRef: true
    minimumReplicaSpread: 1
    ranges:
    - max_replicas: 6
      min_replicas: 3

